# I try to create a vocabulary loop in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops

I am trying to make an app that alike vocabulary card.
I have an Answer array(array size = 4).
I am creating random an english word then I am adding true value of english word in answer array and I am removing true value of english word in turkish array in order to not use  again in random.I am doing same things to other answer array include wrong value.

Problem is that array size is going to 0.for example my total array 20 .when I remove true value,array size is going to  19-18-17... per click then program close.

Here is my code:

```
package de.murattekinlive.pwords;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class WordsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
TextView deneme;
DataBase dataBase;
Button btn_r1,btn_r2,btn_r3,btn_r4;
String [] TR_WORDS;
String [] EN_WORDS;
String [] Answer;
int control_id = 0;
int random ;
Random control;
Random rnd;
int tr,en;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    deneme   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    dataBase = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
    rnd= new Random();

    btn_r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_random1);
    btn_r1.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener());
    btn_r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_random2);
    btn_r2.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener());
    btn_r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_random3);
    btn_r3.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener());
    btn_r4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_random4);
    btn_r4.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener());

    ArrayList<Words> enWordlist  = (ArrayList<Words>) dataBase.allEnWords();
    ArrayList<Words> trWordlist  =(ArrayList<Words>) dataBase.allTrWords();

    TR_WORDS = new String[trWordlist.size()];
    EN_WORDS = new String[enWordlist.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<enWordlist.size();i++){
        EN_WORDS[i] =enWordlist.get(i).getWORD().toString();
        TR_WORDS[i] =trWordlist.get(i).getTR1().toString();
    }


    tr = new Random().nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);

        /*btn_r1.setText(TR_WORDS[en]);
        btn_r2.setText(TR_WORDS[new Random().nextInt(TR_WORDS.length)]);
        btn_r3.setText(TR_WORDS[new Random().nextInt(TR_WORDS.length)]);
        btn_r4.setText(TR_WORDS[new Random().nextInt(TR_WORDS.length)]);*/

    ReStart();

}

private class myClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){

        switch ( v.getId() ) {
            case R.id.button_random1:
                break;
            case R.id.button_random2:
                break;
            case R.id.button_random3:
                break;
            case R.id.button_random4:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        WordsActivity.this.ReStart();
    }

}

public void ReStart(){


    Answer = new String[4];
    control = new Random();
    control_id = control.nextInt(4);
    en = new Random().nextInt(EN_WORDS.length);

    final List<String> newTRList = new ArrayList<>();
    textView.setText(EN_WORDS[en]);
    final int sayi1,sayi2;
    sayi1 = TR_WORDS.length;
    Collections.addAll(newTRList,TR_WORDS);

    // I added true turkish word in answer array
    for(int i=0;i<TR_WORDS.length;i++){
        if(en == i){
            Answer[control_id]=TR_WORDS[i].toString();
            newTRList.remove(TR_WORDS[i].toString()); //remove true value from array in order to not use again.
        }
    }

    TR_WORDS = newTRList.toArray(new String[newTRList.size()]);

    //I added another values in answer array and I want to remove values that is used because
    //I dont want to see same value in answer array.
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        if(i == control_id){

        }
        else if(i == 0){
            random=rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 1){
            random=rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 2){
            random=rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 3){
            random=rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
    }
    sayi2 =TR_WORDS.length;

    deneme.setText(sayi1+"/"+sayi2);

    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){

        if(i == control_id){

        }
        else if(i == 0){
            random =rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 1){
            random =rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 2){
            random =rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }
        else if(i == 3){
            random =rnd.nextInt(TR_WORDS.length);
            Answer[i]=TR_WORDS[random];
        }

    }

    for(int j=0;j<=3;j++){

        if(j==0){
            btn_r1.setText(Answer[j].toString());
        }
        else if(j==1){
            btn_r2.setText(Answer[j].toString());
        }
        else if(j==2){
            btn_r3.setText(Answer[j].toString());
        }
        else if(j==3){
            btn_r4.setText(Answer[j].toString());
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you check your logcat and share the error log and mark the line it's pointing to please?

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to:

```
for(int i=TR_WORDS.length; i >=0 ;i--){
    if(en == i){
        Answer[control_id]=TR_WORDS[i].toString();
        newTRList.remove(TR_WORDS[i].toString()); //remove true value from array in order to not use again.
    }
}
```

And all the other ones that include a remove in a similar a fashion.